# How to run a scala application on Spark standalone cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to set up a standalone spark cluster on my Windows machine and run a scala application in the form a jar that would simply read a 100MB CSV file and write it into another location. I am able to setup a master and two slaves with 8 cores and 6.9 GB ram each. However, when I try to run the application, the master although is able to launch two executors but the application does not run.

Here are the logs of master:

```
2019-05-10 18:29:36 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service on port 6066.
2019-05-10 18:29:36 INFO  StandaloneRestServer:54 - Started REST server for submitting app
lications on port 6066
2019-05-10 18:29:36 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@a767b
a6{/metrics/master/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-05-10 18:29:36 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5a51c
966{/metrics/applications/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-05-10 18:29:36 INFO  Master:54 - I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
2019-05-10 18:40:33 INFO  Master:54 - Registering worker 192.168.8.102:50470 with 8 cores,
 6.9 GB RAM
2019-05-10 18:40:42 INFO  Master:54 - Registering worker 192.168.8.102:50523 with 8 cores,
 6.9 GB RAM
2019-05-10 18:42:39 INFO  Master:54 - Driver submitted org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Driv
erWrapper
2019-05-10 18:42:39 INFO  Master:54 - Launching driver driver-20190510184239-0000 on worke
r worker-20190510184041-192.168.8.102-50523
2019-05-10 18:42:50 WARN  TransportChannelHandler:78 - Exception in connection from /192.1
68.8.102:50746
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.ja
va:288)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1106)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:
343)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteC
hannel.java:123)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.jav
a:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecu
tor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(Defa
ultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-10 18:42:50 WARN  TransportChannelHandler:78 - Exception in connection from /192.1
68.8.102:50791
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.ja
va:288)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1106)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:
343)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteC
hannel.java:123)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.jav
a:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecu
tor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(Defa
ultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-10 18:42:50 INFO  Master:54 - 192.168.8.102:50746 got disassociated, removing it.
2019-05-10 18:42:50 INFO  Master:54 - 192.168.8.102:50791 got disassociated, removing it.
2019-05-10 18:42:50 INFO  Master:54 - 192.168.8.102:50790 got disassociated, removing it.
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  Master:54 - Registering app spark session example
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  Master:54 - Registered app spark session example with ID app-201
90510184256-0000
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20190510184256-0000/0 on work
er worker-20190510184032-192.168.8.102-50470
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20190510184256-0000/0 because
it is EXITED
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20190510184256-0000/1 on work
er worker-20190510184032-192.168.8.102-50470
2019-05-10 18:43:20 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20190510184256-0000/1 because
it is EXITED
```

and slave

```
>2019-05-10 18:40:32 INFO  WorkerWebUI:54 - Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at ht
tp://ws-tujain.ivp.co.in:8081
2019-05-10 18:40:32 INFO  Worker:54 - Connecting to master 192.168.8.102:7077...
2019-05-10 18:40:32 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@28299
58e{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-05-10 18:40:32 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to
/192.168.8.102:7077 after 81 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2019-05-10 18:40:33 INFO  Worker:54 - Successfully registered with master spark://192.168.
8.102:7077
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20190510184256-0000/0 f
or spark session example
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: tujain
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: tujain
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; u
i acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(tujain); groups with view permissions:
Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(tujain); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-05-10 18:42:56 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.
8.0_131\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\Spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\Spark\jars\*" "-Xmx6144M" "-Dspark.drive
r.port=50875" "-Dspark.network.timeout=300s" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "org.apache.spar
k.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws
-tujain.ivp.co.in:50875" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.8.102" "--cores" "8" "-
-app-id" "app-20190510184256-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.102:50470"
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  Worker:54 - Executor app-20190510184256-0000/0 finished with sta
te EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20190510184256-0000/1 f
or spark session example
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: tujain
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: tujain
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; u
i acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(tujain); groups with view permissions:
Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(tujain); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-05-10 18:43:08 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.
8.0_131\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\Spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\Spark\jars\*" "-Xmx6144M" "-Dspark.drive
r.port=50875" "-Dspark.network.timeout=300s" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "org.apache.spar
k.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws
-tujain.ivp.co.in:50875" "--executor-id" "1" "--hostname" "192.168.8.102" "--cores" "8" "-
-app-id" "app-20190510184256-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.102:50470"
2019-05-10 18:43:20 INFO  Worker:54 - Executor app-20190510184256-0000/1 finished with sta
te EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
2019-05-10 18:43:20 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20190510184256-0000/2 f
or spark session example
2019-05-10 18:43:20 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: tujain
2019-05-10 18:43:20 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: tujain
2019-05-10 18:43:20 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-05-10 18:43:20 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
```

Application code :

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://192.168.8.102:7077")
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "6g")
        .set("spark.driver.memory", "6g")
        .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
        .set("spark.network.timeout", "300s")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf = conf)
        .appName("spark session example").getOrCreate()   

    var df = spark.read.format("csv")
        .text("C:\\work\\spark\\Dummy100MBFile.csv")
    df.show(10)
    df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .save("C:\\work\\spark\\output")
}
```

I expected the application to split the data and dump it in multiple files (2 files to be specific since there are 2 workers). However, the master keeps removing and launching executors.

EDIT: 
After running below
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\Spark\bin..\conf\;C:\Spark\jars*" "-Xmx6144M" "-Dspark.driver.port=50875" "-Dspark.network.timeout=300s" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws-tujain.ivp.co.in:50875" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.8.102" "--cores" "8" "--app-id" "app-20190510184256-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.102:50470"

[Click here for manual attempt result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0mOv.png)

Comment: Are you running both the slaves on the same machine? If yes, do you've 6 + 6 GB for both the workers and enough memory for the master too on your laptop? For reading 100MB file you can start with just 1GB memory for each slave. 

Also is both the workers able to start properly? Because the default webUI port of workers is 8081, if you're running both simultaneously they might lead to conflict if the default properties are not changed.

Comment: Yes, both slaves are on same machine. I tried with 1 GB memory to both workers as well but that did not help. Yes the workers seem to start properly as per logs. Also, I checked the webUI. 8080 is master, 8081 and 8082 are slaves.

Comment: Your executor tasks are getting killed with exit code of 1.

Comment: Can you run the following command on a terminal and share the output? 
```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.
8.0_131\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\Spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\Spark\jars\*" "-Xmx6144M" "-Dspark.drive
r.port=50875" "-Dspark.network.timeout=300s" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "org.apache.spar
k.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws
-tujain.ivp.co.in:50875" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.8.102" "--cores" "8" "-
-app-id" "app-20190510184256-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.102:50470"```

Comment: I ran :
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\Spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\Spark\jars\*" "-Xmx6144M" "-Dspark.driver.port=50875" "-Dspark.network.timeout=300s" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws-tujain.ivp.co.in:50875" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.8.102" "--cores" "8" "--app-id" "app-20190510184256-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.102:50470"

result screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0mOv.png
basically it failed to connect to mentioned driver port